# Texture2D is turning black

Tags: c#, graphics, xna, textures, xna-4.0

I have a `Texture2D` that I'm loading from the Content Pipeline. That's working fine, but as soon as I try to use `SetData` on a completely different `Texture2D` all of the textures in my game go completely black:

[image: Normal]

[image: Black]

This is in my HUDMeter class, the class that I want to be just red

```
Texture2D colorGrad = Content.Load<Texture2D>(GradientAsset);

Color[,] pixels = new Color[colorGrad.Width, colorGrad.Height];

Color[] pixels1D = new Color[colorGrad.Width * colorGrad.Height];

pixels = GetRedChannel(colorGrad);

pixels1D = Color2DToColor1D(pixels, colorGrad.Width);

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(pixels[32,32]);
Gradient = colorGrad;
Gradient.SetData<Color>(pixels1D);
```

These are using Riemers tutorial

```
protected Color[,] GetRedChannel(Texture2D texture)
{
    Color[,] pixels = TextureTo2DArray(texture);

    Color[,] output = new Color[texture.Width, texture.Height];

    for (int x = 0; x < texture.Width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < texture.Height; y++)
        {
            output[x,y] = new Color(pixels[x,y].G, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    return output;
}

protected Color[,] TextureTo2DArray(Texture2D texture)
{
    Color[] colors1D = new Color[texture.Width * texture.Height];
    texture.GetData(colors1D);

    Color[,] colors2D = new Color[texture.Width, texture.Height];
    for (int x = 0; x < texture.Width; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < texture.Height; y++)
            colors2D[x, y] = colors1D[x + y * texture.Width];

    return colors2D;
}

private Color[] Color2DToColor1D (Color[,] colors, int width)
{
    Color[] output = new Color[colors.Length];

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < colors.Length / width; y++)
        {
            output[x + y * width] = colors[x % width, y % (colors.Length/width)];
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

And here is the code to draw the sprites, this works fine and is how I always draw sprites:

```
batch.Draw(meter.Gradient, new Vector2(X, Y), Color.White);
```

Update:

I've actually found that the sprites that don't use the same file are not black. Does Texture2D.SetData<>() actually change the file itself? what is the use of that?

Update:

I just tried to use the Alpha as well as RGB and it's working. I'm thinking that there's something wrong with one of the conversion methods.

Comment: oh right, that might be a little difficult. It's spread over 3 classes, but i can post the method where I use SetData (probably the wrong way)

Comment: It would be worth posting *where* this is called as well.

Comment: You use the green channel when reading the red channel, is this correct?

Comment: That's just to test if it's working, since there is no red channel for this sprite

Comment: By the way, the second sprite shown here is part of a different class and completely seperate, so I dont know why it's also black.

Comment: Where's the code for drawing the sprites?

Comment: Texture2D.SetData<>() modifies the file in memory. If you have multiple sprites pointing to the same instance of the file in memory, then all will experience the same problem.

Comment: Ok, so now that that's out of the way, my original question was about why they are turning black?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do this:

```
Texture2D textureA = Content.Load<Texture2D>("MyTexture");
Texture2D textureB = Content.Load<Texture2D>("MyTexture");
```

Both `textureA` and `textureB` refer to the same object. So if you call `SetData` on one of them, it will affect both of them. This is because `ContentManager` keeps an internal list of resources already loaded, so it doesn't have to keep reloading the same resource.

The solution would be to create a new `Texture2D` object of the same size, call `GetData` on the one loaded by `ContentManager`, and then `SetData` on the new texture.

Example (not tested):

```
Color[] buffer = new Color[textureA.Width * textureA.Height];
Texture2D textureB = new Texture2D(textureA.GraphicsDevice,
                                   textureA.Width,
                                   textureA.Height);
textureA.GetData(buffer);
textureB.SetData(buffer);
```

`Dispose()` of the new texture when you are finished with it (eg: in your `Game.UnloadContent` method). But never dispose of the one loaded by `ContentManager` (because, like I said, it is a shared object; use `ContentManager.Unload` instead).

Comment: I don't really know how to use Texture2D SetData and GetData, it doesn't make sense to store a bitmap in a 1D array

Comment: Retrievals are slower as you have two array accesses instead of one. Anyways it goes from left to right then up to down just like a book so simply do ColorArray[(y * width) + x] instead of 2DColorArray[X][Y].

Comment: @ClassicThunder Although for a `[,]` style array, as the OP is using, the speed is the same because it uses the same `(y*width)+x` under-the-hood. The reason it is a 1D array, though, is because you are working with memory buffers - note how you can specify a starting index. This allows you do to more memory-reuse tricks.